# ExtJS 5.1: Treepanel as navigation panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Im using ExtJS 5.1.
I have a Viewport with a `Ext.tree.Panel` at west region and a simple `Ext.panel.Panel` at a center region. When you click one item of the treepanel i want to load some data inside `Ext.panel.Panel` at the center region but i don't know exactly how to do. 
Now i have an `itemclick` listener in `Ext.tree.Panel` who obtain the id of the clicked item. what more do i need to create something like this [ExtJS 4 example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#framed-panels) ?

APP.JS code:

```
    var arbolFrameworks = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title : 'Arbol Frameworks',
        width : 300,
        height : 600,
        style: 'padding: 3 3 3 3;',
        listeners : {
            itemclick : function (view, record, item, index, e) {
                alert(record.getId()); 
            }
        },
        root : {
            text : 'Componentes',
            expanded : true,
            children : [{
                    text : 'Grids',
                    expanded : true,
                    children :
                    [   {
                            id: 'grid_framework',
                            text : 'Grid de frameworks',
                            leaf : true
                        }, {
                            id: 'grid_personaje',
                            text : 'Grid de personajes',
                            leaf : true
                        }
                    ]
                },{
                    text : 'Árbol',
                    expanded : true,
                    children : [{
                            id: 'arbol_prueba',
                            text : 'Arbol de prueba',
                            leaf : true
                        }
                    ]
                },{
                    text : 'Gráficas',
                    expanded : true,
                    children : [{
                            id: 'grafica_1',
                            text : 'Básica',
                            leaf : true
                        },{
                            id: 'gráfica_2',
                            text : 'Pie',
                            leaf : true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });


    var contenido =  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Prueba',
        style: 'padding: 3 3 3 3',
        html: 'prueba'
    })


// Panel
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout:'border',
    defaults: {
        collapsible: true,
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Barra de navegacion',
        region:'west',
        width: 300,
        items:[arbolFrameworks]
    },{
        title: 'Contenido principal',
        collapsible: false,
        region:'center',
        items: [contenido]
    }] 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what more do i need to create something like this [ExtJS 4 example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#framed-panels) ?

In a nut shell, once you've got the `id` of the clicked item, you make an AJAX call to retrieve the relevant content and, in the callback, do `contenido.update(contentFromServer)`.

Looking at the source code of the example, installing and playing with it locally will help a lot.